# Save Computational Time Filtering Collisions

Tags: collision-detection, coronasdk

I have a lot of objects A's(~40 up to 50) which shouldn't collide with each other and another object B which should instead collide with the A's.

Is there a way to **save computational time and resources** and still accomplish this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

According to Corona's documentation, the answer is yes: http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/physics/collisionDetection/index.html#filtering

It would seem you can define your filters as:

```
local redCollisionFilter = { categoryBits = 2, maskBits = 5 } 
-- red collides with (4 and 1) only

local blueCollisionFilter = { categoryBits = 4, maskBits = 7 } 
-- blue collides with (4, 2 and 1) only
```

Note that I didn't test this, but should work based on documentation

Comment: Thank you Alex I already knew this but does it really save computational time?

Comment: I assume, your objects will be "Dynamic" bodies. In this case you have no other option but masking. If the performance is not as expected, you can try some configurations to decrease number of calculations. For example:
physics.setContinuous( false ); physics.setPositionIterations( 4 );
physics.setVelocityIterations( 2 );  etc...

Comment: Federico, I don't know if this would save computational time. Even if you test it, the performance may change in later release, I suppose. If you need it to be as fast as possible (as opposed to fast-enough), I believe corona says to not use physics engine: http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2013/07/23/tutorial-non-physics-collision-detection/